# Postgresql: faster to SORT BY or sort after?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

Where I need entries returned from a postgresql table to be sorted based on the data in one of the columns, is it generally faster to do this as part of the query:

```
const arr = database.query("SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE key='a3zd' ORDER BY timestamp;");
```

... or to request unsorted data and then sort after:

```
const arr = database.query("SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE key='a3zd';");
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a.timestamp - b.timestamp; });
```

Assume that the database and the processing code are hosted on the same server (in my case, `docker` / `node.js`) so there is no difference in terms of processing power for the sort operation.

My gut feeling is that the time taken for a sort operation will be roughly equivalent no matter where it is performed, but I don't know if the internal structures within a postgresql database makes it more efficient to do the sorting internally.

Does it make a difference whether or not the column on which the sort is carried out (`timestamp` here) is indexed?  Or on the amount of data concerned (in my case there would typically be around 5000 entries to sort)?

Comment: Why don't you measure this? And Yes, it's most likely that an index improves performance, but also something you have to check. Same thing using an index on the WHERE condition, maybe in combination the the timestamp.

Comment: It seemed like it's such a simple question that there must already be an answer (but I couldn't find it), without having to re-invent the wheel... I figured that for those who know in depth about databases they would know immediately that it's always faster to do these sorts of basic operations inside rather than outside.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and agree with @FrankHeikens in saying that sorting using an index on the DB should generally be faster than sorting the resulting array. The difference is unlikely to be noticeable with just a few thousand entries to sort though.

Comment: are you worried about just the sort performance or the overall performance of the operation? for 5000 rows it won't matter much unless your table has 1000 columns. index on timestamp won't matter as the index will just point you to the data on disk. however, index on the key will matter as it will make your SQL faster 

but as I said since its 5000 rows the entire table will be loaded in memory given you have enough ram. If you plan on scaling this table to million rows then its a different story